# Custom Title Bar Color for native C++ app on Windows 10

Tags: c++, winapi, titlebar, windows-10

Windows 10 supposedly gives developers the freedom to change their own titlebar colors. I have found a few resources on how to do this for Windows Store apps ([here](http://compiledexperience.com/blog/posts/windows-10-title-bar), [here](http://blog.thomasnigro.fr/2015/02/11/exploring-w10-apis-windows-and-titlebar/)).

But what is the underlying Windows API function for it? How can this effect be achieved in native C++?

Comment: It wouldn't surprise me if desktop apps aren't able to do this. Microsoft don't like the desktop any more.

Comment: I assume the regular non-client painting code relies on the current theme (visual style).  The caption colors seem to be properties window theme.  I wonder if there's a way to tweak those properties of the theme used for your window.

Comment: After all these years, I found ... [something](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa969538(v=vs.85).aspx) ... Though I'm not quite certain how useful this is.

Comment: Man, I know it's been 6 years... But have you found an answer?

Comment: @gavrilikhin.d Not really, I didn't try out the stuff in my previous comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is now done with DWM : [Custom Window Frame Using DWM](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/dwm/customframe)

(tested on Windows 10 in C++, C# and VB.NET by drawing gradient caption bars)

Comment: As it stands, this is essentially a link-only answer. Please summarize the referenced document.

Comment: The linked resource is a bit short on examples with images; I found the following very helpful to get an idea of how all these options look: [link](https://weblogs.asp.net/kennykerr/Windows-Vista-for-Developers-_1320_-Part-3-_1320_-The-Desktop-Window-Manager)

Answer (score 0):

You always could change the color of the title bar in Windows. Simply handle [`WM_NCPAINT`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd145212(v=vs.85).aspx) and paint away!

Comment: Ooh, easy! And who's going to solve the bigger problem that you created by handling `WM_NCPAINT`? You know, like rendering min/max buttons, and the title caption, or an icon maybe. That sort of thing.

Comment: The comment above is the epitome of stack overflow.